# Dates on the activity tab are misleading/incomplete for previous years

Tags: bug, profile-page, recent-activity, pagination

I'm trying to get a user's activities around a certain date by a "half split" search on the user's activities tab (AKA *all actions* tab).

But consider [page 85 of some user's actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt?tab=activity&sort=all&page=85). It looks like this:

[image: bad dates]

But **what year is that**?

It **should look like the following for anything not in the current year:**

[image: good dates]

---

Note: I know that *Desktop* users can *usually* hover over the partial date to get a full datetime string.
But, *requiring* that for such basic/crucial date info is:

1. It doesn't work with touch screens.
2. Bad UI that makes it much more cumbersome to locate the right results.
3. The text can't be highlighted or copied.

Comment: @ShadowWizard,  I filtered on the [recent-activity] tag  -- which that Q did not have until I just now added it -- and so missed that question in searches.